# How do i create new variables inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

I am trying to create new variables depending on how many elements are stored inside a list.

It would have to look something like this:

```
dict  = {}
list = [1,  2, 3, 4]
for obj in list:
  if obj not in dict: 
      dict[obj] = var + obj = None
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `dict[obj] = var + obj = None` - what are you trying to do with `= None` here? (not valid Python syntax)

Comment: you mean add new key+vals, or append values to a given key?

Comment: furthermore, python is very tab pedantic... your if statement looks weird ...

Comment: Also - what is `var` supposed to be here?

Comment: = none is  going to be used for a  string (i put none as an example)

Comment: var + obj is supposed to be a new variable with a number attached to it

Comment: What is your desired result? As a beginner, your terminology hasn't aligned with standard Python usage yet, so it's generally better to show rather than tell until it does. We've all gone through that at some point.

Comment: @DorusBlanken What do you want to get in your result?  Put a sample of your output

Comment: my desired result is that this loop will create new variables depending on the numbers contained in the list.

Comment: @DorusBlanken What is `var` here

Comment: @DorusBlanken, You can't create new variable like you are trying to do, Instead populate the dictionary with your desired variable name and value like NPE mentioned in his/her answer.

Comment: @Dorus. Please show, in your question, an example of the desired result. As in `{...}`, where you fill in ... with the desired keys and values for your example. The prose is not helping much at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> d = {'var%d' % el: None for el in l}
>>> d
{'var4': None, 'var1': None, 'var3': None, 'var2': None}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new item in dictionary using value from list as a key, you can try this

```
dict[obj] = new_value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constructor classmethod [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) to pre-add any number of keys to a dictionary:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(f'var{x}' for x in lst)
```

OR

```
d = dict.fromkeys(map('var{}'.format, lst))
```

Please don't use the variable names `dict` and `list`. They overwrite the built-in names in your names, so you won't be able to use the built-in classes until you do `del list` and `del dict`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with a longer list with some duplicates:

```
myDict  = {}
    myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 8, 1]
    for obj in myList:
        if obj not in myDict: 
            myDict["var" + str(obj)] = None
```

The output is:

```
myDict {'var1': None, 'var2': None, 'var3': None, 'var4': None, 'var8': None}
```